# Раскритикуйте код по задаче

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, шифрование

Суть задачи: шифратор-дешифратор по методу ришелье (буквы переставляются по заданному ключу, каждая цифра ключа является индексом буквы)

```
class Encode:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    
    def splitToList(self):
        import re 

        result = []
        words = re.split(r'(?:[,|;|:|.|!|?|] | )', self.text)
        for word in words:
            sep = re.split(r'(?:;|,)', word)
            if len(sep) > 1:    
                result.append(sep)
            else:
                result.append(list(word))
        return result  #some abcde --> [['s', 'o', 'm', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]

    def randomKey(words):
        import random

        result = []
        for word in words:
            keyList = [num for num in range (0, len(word))]         #[0, 1, 2, 3]
            random.shuffle(keyList)                                 #[2, 0, 1, 3]
            result.append(list(keyList))                    
        return result                                               #[[2, 0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1, 4]]

    def rishelye(words, keys, encode):
        import copy

        for i in range (len(words)):
            word = words[i]                                         #['s', 'o', 'm', 'e']
            key = keys[i]                                           #[2, 0, 1, 3]
            encodeWord = copy.copy(word)                            

            for j in range(len(word)):                              #'s'
                index = int(key[j])                                 #int (2)

                if encode == True:
                    encodeWord[j] = word[index]                     #some --> mome --> msme --> msoe
                else:
                    encodeWord[index] = word[j]
  
            yield encodeWord

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.text  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    text = Encode(str(input("Введите текст: ")))                    #обьекта класса
    choose = str(input("[r to random key, d to decode]: "))
    listText = Encode.splitToList(text)

    if choose == 'r':
        key = (Encode.randomKey(listText))
        encode = True
    else:
        get_key = Encode(str(input("Введите ключ: ")))
        key = Encode.splitToList(get_key)
        encode = True

    if choose == 'd':   
        encode = False

    result = ''
    for i in Encode.rishelye(listText, key, encode):
        joinText = ''.join(i)
        result += (joinText)
        result += (' ')

    resultKey = ''
    for i in range (len(key)):
        if len(key[i]) >= 11:
            join = ','.join(map(str, key[i]))
        else:
            join = ''.join(map(str, key[i]))
        resultKey += join
        resultKey += (' ')

    print ("\n\nИсходный текст: {}\nЗакодированный текст: {}\nКлюч: {}".format(text, result, resultKey))
```

Comment: С методом шифрования Ришелье, к сожалению не знаком, поэтому раскритиковать не смогу, но мог бы подсказать некоторые нюансы для лучшей читабельности кода: 1) импорты делать в начале скрипта (у вас их нужно записывать перед классом `Encode`. 2) При проверке, если у вас булевое значение в переменной `True`, то его можно не писать. Ваш пример -  `if encode == True:`. Мой пример - `if encode:`. 3) При проверке можете использовать не оператор `==` а `is`.

Comment: Stackoverflow является не форумом для свободного общения на айтишные темы, а базой знаний, где собраны конкретные ответы на конкретные вопросы. Поэтому, пожалуйста, не надо писать сюда такие неконкретные вопросы, как "раскритикуйте код". Спасибо за понимание.